# Make all fraction bars have the same lenght in a set of equations

Tags: equations, fractions

I am a begginer at LaTex
Bassically i want every fraction bar to have the same lenght as the natural lenght of the biggest one
I dont know if it would be better to use other command instead of equations, maybe an array or something like that

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
        \dot { { x }_{ 1 } } = & \enskip { x }_{ 2 }\\
            \dot { { x }_{ 2 } } = & \enskip \frac { \beta \gamma {{ x }_{ 2 }}^{ 2 }(\sin ^{ 2 }{ { x }_{ 3 } } -1)\sin { { x }_{ 3 } }  }{ \varphi \beta -\gamma ^{ 2 }+(\beta ^{ 2 }+\gamma ^{ 2 })\sin ^{ 2 }{ \alpha  }  } \\ 
        &-\frac { 2\beta ^{ 2 }{ x }_{ 2 }{ x }_{ 4 }\cos { { x }_{ 3 } } \sin { { x }_{ 3 } }  }{ \varphi \beta -\gamma ^{ 2 }+(\beta ^{ 2 }+\gamma ^{ 2 })\sin ^{ 2 }{\alpha}  }  \\
             &+\frac { \beta \gamma {\dot { {{ x }_{ 3 }}}^{ 2 }\sin { { x }_{ 3 } } }-\gamma \delta \cos { { x }_{ 3 } }\sin { { x }_{ 3 } }+\beta {\tau}_{\theta} }{ \varphi \beta -\gamma ^{ 2 }+(\beta ^{ 2 }+\gamma ^{ 2 } \sin ^{ 2 }{\alpha}  }
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd type in the diagram. Note `\dot{x}_1`, so the dot is not at a weird position. I also removed several useless and difficult to parse braces. Also `\enskip` is not the right space to use. It should be `\mskip\thickmuskip`, but it's easier to use `&=` instead.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_{1} &= x_{2} \\
\dot{x}_{2}
  &= \frac{\beta\gamma {x_{2}}^{2}(\sin^{2} x_{3} - 1)\sin x_{3}}
          {\varphi\beta - \gamma^{2}+(\beta^{2} + \gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha} \\
  &\qquad
   -\frac{2\beta^{2} x_{2}x_{4}\cos x_{3} \sin x_{3}}
         {\varphi\beta - \gamma^{2} + (\beta^{2} + \gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha} \\
  &\qquad
   +\frac{\beta\gamma{{}\dot{x}_{3}}^{2}\sin x_{3} - \gamma\delta\cos x_{3}\sin x_{3}
          +\beta\tau_{\theta}}
         {\varphi\beta-\gamma^{2}+(\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, if you want to equalize the last two fractions, you can use `eqparbox`.

The first argument to `\eqfrac` is a label (here `A`) unique to the fractions you want to equalize. Note that this might require multiple LaTeX runs, but you get a warning if a rerun is needed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqfrac}[3]{%
% #1 = label for the objects to equalize
% #2 = numerator
% #3 = denominator
  \frac{\eqmakebox[#1][c]{$#2$}}{\eqmakebox[#1][c]{$#3$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_{1} &= x_{2} \\
\dot{x}_{2}
  &= \frac{\beta\gamma {x_{2}}^{2}(\sin^{2} x_{3} - 1)\sin x_{3}}
          {\varphi\beta - \gamma^{2}+(\beta^{2} + \gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha} \\
  &\qquad
   -\eqfrac{A}{2\beta^{2} x_{2}x_{4}\cos x_{3} \sin x_{3}}
              {\varphi\beta - \gamma^{2} + (\beta^{2} + \gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha} \\
  &\qquad
   +\eqfrac{A}{\beta\gamma{{}\dot{x}_{3}}^{2}\sin x_{3} - \gamma\delta\cos x_{3}\sin x_{3}
                 +\beta\tau_{\theta}}
              {\varphi\beta-\gamma^{2}+(\beta^{2}+\gamma^{2})\sin^{2}\alpha}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you really see an improvement? I don't, but it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you know what numerator or denominator is widest then you can measure it right before printing the equation using `\setbox` TeX primitive. Then you can do a construction:

```
{ \hbox to<measured width>{$numerator$} \over denominator }
```

for creating a fractions with wider fraction rule. It looks like:

```
\newbox\tmpbox
\def\centereq#1{\hbox to\wd\tmpbox{\hss$#1$\hss}} 

$$
\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{$\beta \gamma \dot  x_3^2 \sin x_3 
                     - \gamma \delta \cos x_3 \sin x_3 + \beta \tau_\theta $} 
\eqalign{
  \dot x_1  &= x_2 \cr
  \dot x_2  &= { \beta \gamma x_2^2 (\sin^2 x_3 - 1) \sin x_3 \over 
                 \varphi \beta - \gamma^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2) \sin^2 \alpha } \cr 
            &\quad - { \centereq{2\beta^2 x_2  x_4 \cos x_3 \sin x_3} \over
                       \varphi \beta - \gamma^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2) \sin ^2\alpha  } \cr
            &\quad + { \copy\tmpbox \over 
                       \varphi \beta - \gamma ^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2 \sin^2 \alpha  }
}
$$
```

in plain TeX. But you are using LaTeX, so put

```
\newbox\tmpbox 
\def\centereq#1{\hbox to\wd\tmpbox{\hss$#1$\hss}}
```

before `\begin{document}` and the code fragment for your equation looks like:

```
\setbox\tmpbox=\hbox{$\beta \gamma \dot  x_3^2 \sin x_3 
                     - \gamma \delta \cos x_3 \sin x_3 + \beta \tau_\theta $} 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \dot x_1  &= x_2 \cr
  \dot x_2  &= { \beta \gamma x_2^2 (\sin^2 x_3 - 1) \sin x_3 \over 
                 \varphi \beta - \gamma^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2) \sin^2 \alpha } \\ 
            &\quad - { \centereq{2\beta^2 x_2  x_4 \cos x_3 \sin x_3} \over
                       \varphi \beta - \gamma^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2) \sin ^2\alpha  } \\
            &\quad + { \copy\tmpbox \over 
                       \varphi \beta - \gamma ^2 + (\beta^2 + \gamma^2 \sin^2 \alpha  }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: With LaTeX many more tools are available and no guess is necessary.

Comment: Not only LaTeX has more tools. For example OpTeX implements `\eqbox` similarly like in eqparbox package. The problem is that user must run TeX twice.

Comment: Running TeX twice is not really a problem: cross references and bibliographies require it; also error checking needs multiple runs.